# How to don't get empty side after login to shiny dashboard R

Tags: r, authentication, shiny, dashboard

I am question. I created shiny dashboard with login panel with different options of browsing for each role. After logging in, I get a blank page and only after selecting sidebarMenu I can see content. my intention is to get the content of the first from the sidebarMenu list immediately after logging in. Does anyone know how to do it?

Below I attach demo code of my app:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

Logged = FALSE
my_username <- c("test", "test2")
my_password <- c("test", "test2")
my_role <- c("Admin", "Guest")

Login_side <- function(){
  sidebarMenu(id = "tabs")
}
Login_page <- function(){
  tagList(
    div(id = "login",
        fluidRow(br()),
        fluidRow(br()),
        fluidRow(br()),
        fluidRow(br()),
        fluidRow(br()),
        fluidRow(br()),
        fluidRow(br()),
        fluidRow(br()),
        fluidRow(
          column(4, offset = 4, uiOutput("Login_full_box"))
        )
    )
  )
}

Admin_side <- function(){
  sidebarMenu(id = "sbMenu",
              menuItem("test menu", tabName = "test", icon = icon("th"))
  )
}
Admin_page <- function(){
  tabItems(tabItem(tabName = "test", h2("HELLO")))
}

Guest_side <- function(){
  sidebarMenu(id = "sbMenu",
              menuItem("test menu 2", tabName = "test2", icon = icon("th"))
  )
}
Guest_page <- function(){
  tabItems(tabItem(tabName = "test2", h2("HELLO 2")))
}    


ui <- shinyUI( 
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title =  "Dashboard", titleWidth = 190),
    dashboardSidebar(width = 190, uiOutput("side")),
    dashboardBody(height=1000, uiOutput("page"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  USER <- reactiveValues(Logged = FALSE)

  observe({
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE){
      if(!is.null(input$Login)){
        if(input$Login > 0){
          Username <- isolate(input$username)
          Password <- isolate(input$password)
          if(length(Username) > 0 && length(Password) > 0){
            if(my_password[which(my_username==Username)]==Password){
              USER$Logged <- TRUE
              USER$role <- my_role[which(my_username==Username)]
            }
            else {
              USER$Logged <- FALSE
            }
          }
          else {
            USER$Logged <- FALSE
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })

  observe({
    if(USER$Logged == FALSE) {
      output$side <- renderUI({Login_side()})
      output$page <- renderUI({Login_page()})     
    }
    if((USER$Logged == TRUE)){
      if(USER$role == "Admin"){
        output$side <- renderUI({Admin_side()})
        output$page <- renderUI({Admin_page()})
      }
      if(USER$role == "Guest"){
        output$side <- renderUI({Guest_side()})
        output$page <- renderUI({Guest_page()})
      }
    }
  })

  output$Login_full_box <- renderUI({
    box(title =  "Login Panel", 
        width = 12, 
        status = "info",  
        solidHeader = TRUE,
        fluidRow(
          column(3, "Username:"),
          column(9, textInput("username", label = NULL))
        ),   
        fluidRow(
          column(3, "Password:"),
          column(9, passwordInput("password", label = NULL))
        ),         
        fluidRow(
          column(5, offset = 3, actionButton("Login", "Login"))
        )
    )
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/authentication-and-database.html

Comment: Thx, but it is not dashboard. Do you know how to update my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `tabName`s to have the same name (they'll never exist at the same time):

```
Admin_side <- function(){
  sidebarMenu(id = "sbMenu",
              menuItem("test menu", tabName = "test", icon = icon("th"), selected = TRUE)
  )
}

Guest_side <- function(){
  sidebarMenu(id = "sbMenu",
              menuItem("test menu 2", tabName = "test", icon = icon("th"))
  )
}
```

Then change your login observer to an `observeEvent` and add an `updateTabsetPanel`:

```
observeEvent(input$Login, {
  if(USER$Logged == FALSE) {
    output$side <- renderUI({Login_side()})
    output$page <- renderUI({Login_page()})     
  }
  if((USER$Logged == TRUE)){
    if(USER$role == "Admin"){
      output$side <- renderUI({Admin_side()})
      output$page <- renderUI({Admin_page()})
    }
    if(USER$role == "Guest"){
      output$side <- renderUI({Guest_side()})
      output$page <- renderUI({Guest_page()})
    }
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "sbMenu", selected = "test")
  }
})
```